# Make flex container expand and overflow its container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How do I make a flex parent with a `nowrap` flex-wrap expand to fit its content even if that means overflowing whatever is wrapping the parent?

Basically, the content has a min-width, **I want the flex parent not to shrink more than the space all the flex items need.**

Here is a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/lazamar/odat477r/

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 180px;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.child {
  display: block;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 10px;
  min-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Content</div>
    <div class="child">Content</div>
    <div class="child">Content</div>
    <div class="child">Content</div>
    <div class="child">Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want `.parent` to be same width as sum of its children?

Comment: Yes. Taking into consideration not only the children's width, but their margins and the parent's padding as well.

Comment: Then you should use `display:inline-flex` on your `.parent` instead of `display: flex`. Also you need to remove `min-width`

Answer (score 3):

Using `display: inline-flex` instead of `display: flex` is your best bet.

If, for any reason, that's not an option, use CSS positioning properties.

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 180px;
  position: relative;             /* new; set bounding box for flex container  */
  min-height: 40px;               /* new */
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;             /* new; remove flex container from document flow */
}

.child {
  /* display: block;              <-- not necessary */
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 10px;
  min-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Content</div>
    <div class="child">Content</div>
    <div class="child">Content</div>
    <div class="child">Content</div>
    <div class="child">Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Similar problem and tried your solution but no luck.
I can not set min-width on child, it should be dynamic
flex container is inside a fix width container I want to flexbox to expand as it's child grows
https://jsfiddle.net/shankarregmi/az7vqoup/3/ 
I want the red background to cover the whole content

Comment: How about adding the red background to `.menu-list`? https://jsfiddle.net/kzu1qa8h/ @ShankarRegmi

Comment: I had that red background just to distinguish my menu. I want the menu container expand proportionally with menu-list @Michael Bebnjamin

Comment: Got it. Make the top-level wrapper a flex container. Disable shrink on `.menu`. https://jsfiddle.net/kuq8L57f/ @ShankarRegmi

Answer (score 3):

The answer is what t1m0n said. Use **`display: inline-flex`** instead of `display: flex` for the parent.

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 180px;
}
.parent {
  display: inline-flex; /* -- only change --*/
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.child {
  display: block;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 10px;
  min-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Content</div>
    <div class="child">Content</div>
    <div class="child">Content</div>
    <div class="child">Content</div>
    <div class="child">Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any visual difference to OPs example